# Formatting SD card in Linux from C++ application without using system

Tags: c++, linux, bash, format, filesystems

I have an application where I'm writing data on the removable media (SD card/ pendrive). Now, I want to add a functionality where I can format the SD card in case it's not mounted properly or got corrupted for any reason.

I know I can use system() method to call an underlying utility like mkfs.ext4 for formatting the removable partition as we do via terminal, or a bash script which will unmount, format and remount the removable media. But I would like to avoid system() call because:

It spawns a new shell over which I will have no control.
In this particular case, I cannot check the status of unmounting/ formatting/ remounting, which prevents me from proper error handling in the application.
Is there a system library I can use to do the same task in C++ way (using APIs/ method calls) rather than having to call system() and then a bash script within.

Please correct if I misunderstood something.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such think in linux afaik. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166750/writing-an-ext4-file-system-in-c) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the libext2fs-dev and e2fslibs-dev packages (see function `ext2fs_initialize` in ext2fs/ext2fs.h).

[This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs) is what linux distributions are using to handle such filesystems, but the documentation is a bit scarce:

> ### 2.1.3 Initializing a filesystem
>
> An ext2 filesystem is initializing by the 'mke2fs' program.  The two
>   functions described here, 'ext2fs_initialize' and
>   'ext2fs_allocate_tables' do much of the initial work for setting up a
>   filesystem.  However, they don't do the whole job.  'mke2fs' calls
>   'ext2fs_initialize' to set up the filesystem superblock, and calls
>   'ext2fs_allocate_tables' to allocate space for the inode table, and
>   the inode and block bitmaps.  In addition, 'mke2fs' must also
>   initialize the inode tables by clearing them with zeros, create the
>   root and lost+found directories, and reserve the reserved inodes.

The quote is from the generated doc of a snapshot of the project (git repo https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git)

I also found [this online pdf file](http://www.giis.co.in/libext2fs.pdf) if you want to have a quick look...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Is there something similar for ext4 or fat32?

Comment: The library is called ext2 but it should handle the newer versions too.